# Login is Not Working Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hello friends I am using users table column like (USERNAME,EMAIL,PASSWORD)
if i am changing to column name as small letters is working fine. To Change column name as caps is not working give me any suggestion

This is my controller

```
  public function postLogin(Request $request)
   {
     $this->validate($request, array('username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required'));
    $credentials = $request->only('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD');

    if (Auth::validate($credentials)) 
    {
        $user = Auth::getLastAttempted();
        Auth::login($user, $request->has('remember'));
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }
    return redirect($this->loginPath())
    ->withInput($request->only('USERNAME', 'remember'))
    ->withErrors([
        'username' => $this->getFailedLoginMessage(),
    ]);

}
```

Comment: "is not working for me" does not describe the problem at all. Clearify what errors you receive.

Comment: Invalid username and password this is the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both user providers that you get with Laravel (**EloquentUserProvider** and **DatabaseUserProvider**) expect password to be stored in lowercase **password** field.

In order to make authentication work with **PASSWORD** field you need to do 2 things.

First, let providers know that user's password is stored in **PASSWORD** column. You can do this by implementing **getAuthPassword** method in your **User** model:

```
public function getAuthPassword() {
  return $this->PASSWORD;
}
```

Secondly, password needs to be stored with **password** key in the credentials array you pass to **Auth::validate()**. You'll need to change the name of the name of the form field that user inputs password into to **password** OR create credentials array manually:

```
$credentials = [
  'USERNAME' => $request->get('USERNAME'),
  'password' => $request->get('PASSWORD'),
];
```